# Как правильно сделать функцию, которая создает и возвращает DOM-узел карточки?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно создайте функцию createMovieCard(), которая 
  создает и возвращает DOM-узел карточки кинофильма.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.movie {
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #212121;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.movie__image {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.movie__body {
  padding: 8px;
}

.movie__title {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.movie__description {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  vertical-align: top;

  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 2.8;
  color: #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;

  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;

  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: background-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="movie">
  <img class="movie__image" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/rPdtLWNsZmAtoZl9PK7S2wE3qiS.jpg" alt="movie image">
  
  <div class="movie__body">
    <h2 class="movie__title">The Godfather</h2>
    <p class="movie__description">Spanning the years 1945 to 1955, a chronicle of the fictional Italian-American Corleone crime family. When organized crime family patriarch, Vito Corleone barely survives an attempt on his life, his youngest son, Michael steps in to take care of the
      would-be killers, launching a campaign of bloody revenge.</p>

    <p class="movie__date">Released: 1972-03-14</p>
    <p class="movie__rating">Rating: 8.6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно использовать createElement для создания узлов.
  Добавить классы и атрибуты. Правильно ли будет решить задачу с помощью клонирования?

Comment: Что конкретно у Вас не получается? Привидите примеры Ваших попыток

Comment: сейчас исправлю )

Comment: ```const card = document.querySelector('.movie');
const img = document.querySelector('.movie__image').cloneNode(true);
const body = document.querySelector('.movie__body');
const title = document.querySelector('.movie__title').cloneNode(true);
const description = document
  .querySelector('.movie__description')
  .cloneNode(true);
const date = document.querySelector('.movie__date');
const rating = document.querySelector('.movie__rating');

// const clone = title.cloneNode(true);
card.appendChild(img);
card.appendChild(title);
card.appendChild(description);```

Comment: я делала с помощью клонирования а это не правильный способ так как нужно создать функцию которая создаст и возвратит карточку

Comment: если Вы почитаете про работу метода `createElement`  - я уверен, у Вас все получится сделать самостоятельно. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement Там ничего сложного

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать )))

Comment: Запостите потом результат, как ответ. А мы проведем code-review или предложим свой вариант

Comment: Хорошо) Ответ уже крутится в голове)

Comment: что-то у меня не получается( ступор

Comment: ну вот, теперь покажите то, что не получается

Comment: Я решила создавать элементы img h2 b так дальше и вставлять их в общий div ```const move = document.createElement('img');
move.href = '#';
move.classList.add('movie__image');

const heading = document.createElement('h2');```

Comment: вот пример как я делала